# Want .htaccess to display name instead of id?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am working on site in which their are user profiles, now I want to display the profiles names or say username through .htaccess. For example: my site have a profile of one user the link is given

```
http://websoftnet.com/projects/uklasertherapy/?page_id=62&th_id=3
```

and I want .htaccess to display this

```
http://websoftnet.com/projects/uklasertherapy/profile/saeed
```

How can I do this through .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

The technique is called URL Rewriting. Check this sites out:

1. [URL Rewriting Guide (Apache)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)
2. [URL Rewriting (Your HTML Source)](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Untested code

You need to have a .htaccess file along the lines of

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^projects/uklasertherapy/profile/([a-zA-Z])/$ projects/uklasertherapy/profile.php?name=$1
```

Where `profile.php` would take the variable `name` from the GET parameter and get the page for the user with that name.